# execv and fork: inform parent that child failed to execute the file

Tags: c, fork, waitpid, execv

How can the master process know that the child process failed to execute the file (e.g. no such file or directory)?  For example, in the following code, how can we get run() to return something other than 0?  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

enum ErrorType { noError, immediateFailure, returnFailure, forkFailure };

using namespace std;

int run(void)
{
    int error = noError;
    //char proc[] = "/bin/uname";
    char proc[] = "/usr/bin/Idontexist";
    char *const params[] = {proc, NULL};

    pid_t pid = fork();

    printf("pid = %d\n",pid);

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if ( execv(proc,params)==-1 )
        {
            error = immediateFailure;
        }
        printf("child: error = %d\n",error);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        /*  This is the parent process
         *  incase you want to do something
         *  like wait for the child process to finish
         */
        int waitError;
        waitpid(pid, &waitError, 0);

        if ( waitError )
            error = returnFailure;

        printf("parent: error = %d, waitError = %d\n",error,waitError);
    }
    else
    {
        error = forkFailure;
    }

    return error;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("run() = %d\n",run());

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
pid = 4286
pid = 0
child: error = 1
run() = 1
parent: error = 0, waitError = 0
run() = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the error code from **`main`**, or `exit()` with the value. Now you're `return`ing `0` from `main` in all cases, and that will be the exit code of the child that the parent receives from `waitpid`.

The best fix is to add `_exit(error)` in the child process:

```
printf("child: error = %d\n",error);
_exit(error);
```

---

In any case use integer constants instead of random enum constants enum. 1 and 2 are common return values from many unix commands with 1 meaning that the command was not successful (for example `grep` didn't found any matches), and 2+ meaning that the command really failed (wrong arguments or such)`.

`bash`, `zsh` and other shells use `127` as the exit code to signal *command not found / not runnable*; thus this would be recommended:

```
#define COMMAND_NOT_RUNNABLE 127

/* ... */

execv(proc, params);  // exec never returns if successful.
perror(proc);
_exit(COMMAND_NOT_RUNNABLE);
```

---

The reason to use `_exit` in the child process is that it doesn't flush the stdio buffers (that would exist on the parent side too) and that it doesn't run the `atexit` hooks. (Thanks [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle))

Comment: A bit old, but calling `exit()` after a failed `exec()` after a `fork()` can cause serious problems.  `exit()` will flush all output `FILE *` streams and the data they hold inherited from the parent process's address space. If the parent process is multithreaded that can deadlock if any of the streams were locked by different  threads when `exec()` was called. Functions registered by `atexit()` will also be called. If any C++ code is linked in, static destructors will be called.  `_exit()` is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` don't lead to return to `waitpid() EXIT_FAILURE` status of child process, always `0`. My solution is to `abort()` the child process if `execv()`/`execve()` failed to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the handling of the error after the `execv` fails. The child sets `error` to `immediateFailure` and returns that to `main`. Then `main` prints the error number, and  returns `0`. But `0` means success, so the parent process thinks that the child succeeded.

The solution is to return the error number from `main`, or call `exit` in the child code, e.g.

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    execv(proc,params);
    error = immediateFailure;
    printf("child: error = %d\n",error);
    exit( error );
}
```

Note that you don't need to check the return value from `execv`, since `execv` won't return if it succeeds. It will only return if it fails, and will always return -1.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the proposed `exit(error);` you should give specific options for `waitpid`. Your code did not work for me until I changed the call to `waitpid(pid, &waitError, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);`